# Confusion about a gene's description

Tags: genetics, gene, sequence-alignment

I have a very basic biology question. I am reading the description of gene FAM166A [here](https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=FAM166A&keywords=EXD3), and I have no idea what "sequence similarity 166" means. What does 166 stand for, what is this gene's sequence "similar to"? And what does member A mean?

Comment: Family membership is probably referring to something similar to this: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/course/introduction-protein-classification-ebi/protein-classification/what-are-protein-families. I'm not sure how the sequence similarity is scored, though.

Comment: Oh okay, then this gene named FAM166A is member A of the protein family with *ID 166* where each family is determined based on sequence similarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAM symbols are defined in the [HUGO Gene Nomenclature Committee guidelines.](https://www.genenames.org/about/guidelines)

The FAM symbol is an anonymous and temporary identifier that is given to groups of poorly characterised genes which share more than 40% amino acid sequence identity (see [Section 4.1](https://www.genenames.org/about/guidelines#genefamilies)).

There are two human genes/proteins in the sequence similarity 166 group; [FAM166A and FAM166B.](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=family:%22upf0605%20family%22&fil=organism%3A%22Homo%20sapiens%20%28Human%29%20%5B9606%5D%22) These have some sequence similarity (more than 40%) but  function of this similar sequence is currently unknown. Once further characterisation has been performed for any FAM group they will likely receive more meaningful names.